# Bash, how can I apply one arithmetic expression to every line?

Tags: linux, bash

I have two scripts, A and B.

I want to execute them and read respectively two values. V and VALS.

V is just a floating point number, let's say 0.5

VALS has the following format:

```
1 10
2 20
3 60
4 45
```

and so on.

What I'm trying to do is to get a new variable where the second column of VALS (10, 20, ...) is divided by V.

As I understand this can be implemented with a mix of xargs and cut but I'm not really familiar with these tools.

```
#!/bin/bash

V=`./A`
VALS=`./B`
RESULT=#magic happens
```

The final result with the previous data should be:

```
1 20
2 40
3 120
4 90
```

Comment: Don't tag in title.

Comment: For floating point numbers, you need an external tool.

Comment: post the final `$RESULT` contents

Answer (score 2):

Bash's builtin arithmetic expansion only works for integers. You can use `awk` for data extraction and floating point numbers.

```
V=`./A`
# No VALS needed
RESULT=($(./B | awk "{print \$2 / $V"}))
```

Note the escaped dollar sign in `\$2`.

Comment: What I get is ./script.sh: line 7: 1000: command not found
awk: cmd. line:1: {print $2 / }
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error

Comment: To assign a constant, use `V=1000` without backticks or spaces after the `=`

Comment: `awk -v d "$V" '{print $2 / d}'` would be safer than using shell string interpolation to build a dynamic script.